# open multiple oldfiles

Tags: multiple-files

using `:browse old<cr>` it's possible to view a list of the 100 most recently visited files.

However, when selecting a file to visit, it's only possible to provide a single number and not a sequence of numbers or a range. Indeed, the prompt visible after pressing `:browse<cr>G` does not allow the input of symbols other than `0123456789`.

Is there a separate command that can be used to open a range of oldfiles?

Answer (score 2):

### Plugins

There are plenty of plugins which provide a custom prompt for mru lists and allow you to select several entries:

- [**Mru list by ctrlp.vim**](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)

  1. Open mru list with `<c-p><c-b>` or `:CtrlPMR[UFiles]` or  set `let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMRU'` in your vimrc and then `<c-p>` (my choice).
  2. select entries either via fuzzy search expr or cycle with `<c-j>` and `<c-k>`
  3. Use `<c-z>` to mark/unmark multiple files
  4. Use `<c-o>` to open them.
- [**:History in fzf.vim**](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) (requires go)

  > `TAB` and `Shift-TAB` to mark multiple items
- [**mru.vim**](https://github.com/yegappan/mru)

  > You can open multiple files from the MRU window by specifying a count
  > before pressing '' or 'v' or 'o' or 't'. You can also visually select
  > multiple filenames and invoke the commands to open the files. Each
  > selected file will be opened in a separate window or tab.

Furthermore, you might consider [fzf-mru](https://github.com/pbogut/fzf-mru.vim), [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) (+ruby) and [Denite](https://github.com/Shougo/denite.nvim) (+python3) with [neomru.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neomru.vim).

As far as I haved check [vim-tinyMRU](https://github.com/romainl/vim-tinyMRU) does not allow to do this.

Comment: fzf.vim is a good choice

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing this with no plugins:

It follows the structure of romainl's [Redir.vim](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7) script and writes the output of `oldfiles` (which is not the same thing as `browse oldfiles`) to a temporary buffer opened with a vertical split.

It also defines a function `VisitFilesFromLineRange` that allows a user to visit multiple files at once if a line range in visual line mode is currently active.

I also defined a wrapper function around `VisitFilesFromLineRange` that takes an explicit range argument and rebound `gf` in visual mode so that it ultimately calls `VisitFilesFromLineRange`.

The `Oldfiles` function, by itself, is far more useful than the new `gf` binding in my opinion since it makes it easy to search through the list of old files using ordinary vim bindings.

```
function! Oldfiles()
  " kill all the windows called oldfiles_scratch
  " we don't need them around anymore
  for win in range(1, winnr('$'))
    if getwinvar(win, 'oldfiles_scratch')
      execute win . 'windo close'
    endif
  endfor
  " redirect the stuff that normally prints to the console
  " to the variable "output". Note that in "redir => output"
  " output refers to the variable itself not its contents.
  " If VimL were more like C, this would be written
  "
  "     redir => &output
  "
  redir => output
  execute "oldfiles"
  redir END
  " create a new pane thingy but vertically. seems to create it
  " on the left by default which is cool.
  vnew
  " tag this particular window with out variable outfiles_scratch
  " so we know to kill it later.
  let w:oldfiles_scratch = 1
  " our new window is ephemeral, give it ephemeralish properties.
  " NOTE: explicitly make the buffer modifiable NOW.
  " we set it to nomodifiable after trimming the line numbers.
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile modifiable
  " dump the contents of output as lines
  call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
  " remove the leading numbers. Leading numbers make it harder to ``gf" the lines we want.
  execute "%s/^\\d\\+: //"
  " go to the top line
  execute "1"
  " make it nomodifiable
  setlocal nomodifiable
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 Oldfiles silent call Oldfiles()



function! VisitFilesFromLineRange(low, hi)
  " save the current buffer index
  " so we can read from it later
  let current_buf = bufnr("%")
  " keep track of whether we spawned a new tab already or not
  " there isn't really a convenient way to spawn a truly-empty
  " container tab that we then fill up so it's easier to spawn
  " the container "on demand" as we process our first line
  let did_tabnew = 0
  " walk the array of lines from the buffer
  for line in getbufline(current_buf, a:low, a:hi)
    " escape the line name before doing stuff to it
    let eline = fnameescape(line)
    " perform a horizontal split or tabedit depending on whether
    " the new tab has been created or not
    if did_tabnew
      execute("split " . eline)
    else
      let did_tabnew = 1
      execute("tabedit " . eline)
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ VisitFilesFromLineRange silent call VisitFilesFromLineRange(<f-args>)


" define a function that accepts a range
" and forwards it into VisitFilesFromLineRange with the appropriate arguments
function! RangeFuncVisitFilesFromRange() range
  call VisitFilesFromLineRange(a:firstline, a:lastline)
endfunction
" VisitLines command accepting a range argument for convenience
command! -range VisitLines silent <line1,line2>call RangeFuncVisitFilesFromRange()

" detect visual line mode and call RangeFuncVisitFilesFromRange
" otherwise delegate to the default implementation of "gf" for visual mode
xnoremap <silent> <expr> gf (mode() ==# "V") ? ":call RangeFuncVisitFilesFromRange()\<cr>" : "gf"
```